# if the json value is longer then how to change the json format it into another json format, dynamically need to change in js (nodejs)

Tags: json, node.js

**INPUT:** Input value is looks like this.

```
 { 
            "title" : "new resource",
            "user" : {
                "firstName" : "tester",
                "lastname" : "test"
            }
 }
```

**OUTPUT:** output looks like this

```
{ 
        "title" : "new resource",
        "user.firstName" : "tester",
        "user.lastname" : "test" 
 }
```

In some case the json value may be logner, so we cant put much for loop for each and every set of iteration.

Comment: This is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

By using user.firstName you can reach to the value:"tester"
but its not the change of the format... 
not a good question.